# Loop through object of call signatures

Tags: typescript

A classic way to loop through each properties of an object is to use `Object.keys(object).forEach()`

But if you have an object of call signatures, you can't do the same, because there are no keys.

Ex:

```js
interface Events {
  (evt: 'event', handler: any): void;
  (evt: 'other-event', handler: any): void;
};

// with emit being of type Events
const test = Object.keys(emit)

console.log(test) // returns an empty array
```

So my question is: how do you iterate on such object ?

Edit: Here is more context (this is some Vue3 composition API code). I just would like to avoid repeating the last 3 lines for each call signature in that interface.

```js
const lib = new Lib()
const emit = defineEmits<Events>()

lib.on('event', (handler) => {
  emit('event', handler)
})
```

Comment: What would it even return? It's a **callable** object. Probably a function. How would you "loop" over a function anyways? Also, the call signatures are only available in type space. They don't exist at runtime.

Comment: That's not an object... That's a type/interface, not accessible to JS

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to achieve because this looks like [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @RuanMendes I added some context in the initial post. Tell me if it's still unclear.

Comment: You probably are looking for a way to generate that code based on your interface using the [TypeScript compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API).

Comment: So a basic iteration isn't possible ? Something like `Object.keys(object).forEach((event) => {
    lib.on(event, (options) => {
      emit(event, options)
    })`, but working

Comment: @Synops You seem to have missed my previous comment.  `interface Events` is not accessible to JavaScript, it gets compiled out by `tsc`.

Comment: Ah yeah, it makes more sense indeed. Thanks